# Integrated Terminal VS Code (Problem with special characters)

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-code, gnome-terminal

I've installed the VS Code and the integrated terminal doesn't accept especial characters like "á","é" or ã.
I tried to set the changes on `settings.json` file, tried even to change my language packages and everything that you could imagine.

If somebody knows the solution, could help me, please?

[image: Settings.json and my terminal - the outputs highlighted in red]

Answer (score 1):

I got solved this one!
Seems the problem was on the **zsh** fragmented files in my **usr**, **temp** and **var** **repositories**. I did a search by files names and remove them.
After this procedure, I've updated my package manager apt update and apt-get update and then, reconfigured the Integrated.Terminal.linux and set the source to **bash/shell**.